# Meteor on the OpenShift - fibers do not install/build

Tags: meteor, openshift, node-fibers

Have spent last few days (!) trying various Meteor/OpenShift configurations. There is a little mess, in the short words, but what's the most common problem is the meteor bundle require Fibers module given as the downloadable repo like this

```
 "dependencies": {
   "fibers": "https://github.com/meteor/node-fibers/tarball/d519f0c5971c33d99c902dad346b817e84bab001",
   "meteor-promise": "0.5.0",
   "underscore": "1.5.2",
   "source-map-support": "https://github.com/meteor/node-source-map-support/tarball/1912478769d76e5df4c365e147f25896aee6375e",
   "semver": "4.1.0"
  },
```

but it seems it's not accessible.

```
UNMET DEPENDENCY fibers@https://github.com/meteor/node-fibers/tarball/d519f0c5971c33d99c902dad346b817e84bab001

npm ERR! missing: fibers@https://github.com/meteor/node-fibers/tarball/d519f0c5971c33d99c902dad346b817e84bab001, required by meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0
```

and here the point comes, I have no idea how but I was able to run the meteor app on OpenShift, but only after a number of manual (using ssh console) Fibers installations/deinstalations

```
npm install fibers@1.0.8
npm uninstall fibers
npm install fibers@1.0.5
etc ...
```

and one more ... the link 
https://github.com/meteor/node-fibers/tarball/d519f0c5971c33d99c902dad346b817e84bab001 seems to be valid.

so what's wrong with the

```
 "dependencies": {
       "fibers": "https://github.com/meteor/node-fibers/tarball/d519f0c5971c33d99c902dad346b817e84bab001",
```

??